# Issues installing Kivy on Win 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, kivy

Having problems installing Kivy on windows 10.

Installed everything with instruction from https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html and everyhing have been installed except the kivy itself. I'm using Python 3.9.0. Also couldn't insall properly PyQT, but solved somehow

Error message:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
   command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xeoguf6o'
       cwd: C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-57g12q0m\kivy\
  Complete output (531 lines):
  Using setuptools
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
    Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0l_k634_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\kivy'
         cwd: C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-57g12q0m\kivy\
    Complete output (513 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\kivy

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0l_k634_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.
python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have python 3.8 installed, then Kivy 1.11.1 is not going to work. Because the developers didn't release Kivy 1.11.1 wheel for python 3.8. I was also stuck in this same problem but just found the solution in SO and kivy installation doc. They mentioned that this will work in python 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7.

Either you can download python 3.7 or try the pre-release (master) version of kivy. Just go and see pypi for the command.